# Microphone not recognised in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: sound, microphone, headset

I know there are similar questions but none of them work in my case.

I have Acer Aspire A515-45 laptop with Realtek ALC256 sound card. The problem is that when my headphones with bulit-in mic are connected to it only the headphones are recognised, if I try to connect them while booted into Windows(I have dual boot) option dialog is presented and selecting "Headset" option fixes the problem. Is there a way to do the same on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working exactly the way I wanted it following this video [on YouTube...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYkzX1lyTNk)

This video describes opening a configuration file as follows:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and then pasting the following line at the base of the configuration file:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

Save the changes to this file and then reboot your system...

Hope this helps someone!